# problemas al actualizar datos con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Estoy trabajando con el loadata pero mysql si acepta las "" pero php no,por eso decidi insertado todos los datos en bruto(con loadata pero usando solo campos varchar) en una tabla para depues sobre esos campos hacer operaciones,mi problema es en la ultima consulta
en update tablatemporal="aceptado" quiseria en el mismo query[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Resulta que mi estatus_bboo lo estoy dejando como aceptado cuando debo someterlo a varias condiciones para ver si se queda como aceptado o rechazado,podria despues recorrer la tabla con php pero son miles de datos entonces a la hora de hacer el update quiero hacer la condicion de que si supertoke_id su longitud es mayor a 5 y menor a 10 sea aceptado,eso lo hice con el loadata infile,
por el momento no tengo acceso al sistema pero quiero saber si se puede hacer algo asi en el query

```
        estatus_bboo=
    CASE
WHEN LENGTH(@supertoken_id)<10 && @supertoken_id REGEXP ('^[0-9]+$') && LENGTH(@supertoken_id)>5 THEN 'Aceptado'

ELSE 'Rechazado'
END,
```

Comment: por favor añade código con la herramienta de {} dale formato es mejor y será mejor recibida tu pregunta

Comment: aunque la imagen esta bien, no especificas bien que tipo de error obtienes. seria bueno documentar mas la pregunta.